# mapping curl usage with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl

I'm writing an iPad app that need to communicate with a backend server. The problem is that the code I've got is failing and I don't understand why. When I use 'curl', I get the expected response:

This is the curl usage:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"userName":"foo2@foolinator.com", "password":"password"}' "http://server.local/signature/service/auth/rest/firewall/login" --dump-header headers
```

When I open the 'headers' file, I get what I expected, a response of 302, with information in the cookie. However, my Objective C code gets me a response of 'internal server error':

```
// Create the request.
NSString* loginURL = @"http://server.local/signature/service/auth/rest/firewall/login";
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginURL]];

    NSString* credentials = @"'{\"userName\":\"foo2@foolinator.com\", \"password\":\"password\"}'";
NSData* connectionData = [credentials dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPBody:patientConnectionData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Logging in...
NSError* error = nil;
NSURLResponse* response;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
NSString* mime = [httpResponse MIMEType];
NSString* responseString = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]];
```

The response is Error 500: Internal Server Error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at your server logs, that will probably tell you why.  There's likely some minor difference in the HTTP headers (possibly the User-Agent) which might be tripping up your server.  If you don't have access to your server logs, then try connecting your device through a proxy and get a packet dump with Wireshark to capture and analyze the requests.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get a full dump of the request object?

Comment: No, there's no way to see exactly what data it's sending on the wire without actually inspecting what's on the wire.  I'd suggest setting up your Mac as a Wi-Fi access point (via the Internet Sharing system preference) and then connecting your iPad to that.  Then, run Wireshark on your Mac with a filter capturing just the packets from your device.  If you're using plain HTTP, the full requests will be decoded by Wireshark; but if you're using HTTPS, then that won't work.

Comment: Instead of Wireshark (painful) try CharlesProxy, 30 days free, dragNDrop install.

Comment: I installed CharlesProxy, how do I monitor it now?

Comment: I should add that I installed it and it shows nothing, even with Safari going to google.

Comment: Do you get the Charles window? If you don't have Java installed on yo pour Mac you need the Alderney version that includes Javelin in Charles. Otherwise check the getting started docs. You should by default see all http traffic.

Comment: I do see the window, just no output. It may have something to do with Java on my machine, I hadn't thought of that. What is the URL for the other version you mentioned?

Comment: The link is right below, look for "Alternate version ...".

Answer (score 0):

So using WireShark, I was able to see a successful request with curl go through, and compare it against my code above. It seems that removing the single quotes from the username/password dictionary and changing the body to this line:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[credentials dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                               allowLossyConversion:YES]];
```

Does the trick, kind of ... What happens, per WireShark is that two requests seem to go through, the POST seen in the question and for some reason, a secondary GET, which obviously fails. I don't know why that second request is happening, I'll post that in a separate question.